# QT in Visual Studio using QML, console.log not showing logs when QML is dynamically loaded

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-vs-addin

on our `VS (2017)` environment that uses QT using QT tools for Visual Studio, console.log is not appearing on debug window when QML is dynamically loaded/added using the `component.createObject()` which is called from a QML itself in an MDI manner.

How to work around this?

Comment: What's an MDI?  Also, please provide an example of what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Check out this thread on GitHub. I mentioned several environment variables which may impact logging rules and destination.  https://github.com/woboq/qmetaobject-rs/discussions/163